# How can I add this "emboss" to an object in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, icon

[image]

If you see the light blue highlights on the inside of the logo, that's what I mean.  I don't know how else to describe it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would make something similar using gradients and Gaussian blur.

1. The top "Highlight" object is a copy of the main shape below it, but inset, filled white, with a Gaussian blur applied.
2. The object under that is the main "Shape", a compound path, with a gradient fill (white to a light bluish-grey). It might be possible to use a gradient mesh here instead to position the gradients more accurately in different places.
3. Under that is the "Shadow", a copy of the main shape, but filled with a mix of C and 100% K so that it blends into the background, with a Gaussian blur, and lowered opacity.
4. The "Background" is rounded rectangle filled with a gradient, a lighter to darker blue.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's quite complex - the blue shadow seems to follow the blue gradient in the background. It's not a single color glow nor drop shadow.

Place a reduced opacity white shape on a background rectangle with blending mode normal:

[image]

You need a copy of the white object. To get it easily on top copy the white shape to the clipboard.

Make a reduced size or Offset path copy of the white shape (keep still the copy of the original in the clipboard), let it be fully opaque but insert Gaussian Blur Effect:

[image]

The blur spreads also on the background. That looks bad if the background is dark. To kill the excessive blur paste in place the original white shape and use it as a clipping mask for the blurred white version:

[image]

There seems to be layered another white shape on the top. It needs it own background.